# Writing date to SQL from php, date is changed

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have code in PHP 5.4 that is creating a record in SQL server 2008 r2. The PHP code creates a date:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

which yeilds:

```
'2015-06-23'
```

That date is used in a query to the SQL server:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO AdAttend (AdEnrollSchedID, AdEnrollID, Date, StartTime, Attend, Absent, unitType, Status, Comment, Excused, ModFlag, UserID, DateAdded, DateLstMod, AdClassAttendID, Type)
        VALUES ('.$AdEnrollSchedID.','.$AdEnrollID.','.$date.',\'1899-12-30 07:00:00.000\','.$present.','.$absent.',\'M\',\'A\',\''.$comment.'\',0,\'A\','.$instructorID.
        ','.$date.','.$date.','.$AdClassAttendID.',\'A\')';
```

The query seems to work fine. The record is inserted as it should be. However when I check the record in the table the dates are:

```
 '1905-06-23 00:00:00.000'
```

so the question is, Why is it altering 2015 to be 1905?

Comment: Make sure you sanitize your query parameters. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: only one variable is used from user input and it's not the date. The variable is number which is sanitized before it's used.  Even still, doesn't help solve the problem...

Comment: `$date` is a string and should be quoted - `...,\''.$date.'\',...`. For example, look at your `StartTime` which is also quoted.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to help solve the problem it was meant to point out a potential security hole which everyone may find helpful. That said I use very similar code and it works fine. Maybe a more detailed code snippet would help. Try including the create table syntax and what happens between the date format and insert.

Comment: @Sean  - doh... you got it.  I should have caught that.... maybe it's time to take a break.

Comment: @Gene break from IT field ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Insert escape quotes OR use Double quotes in single quotes

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO AdAttend (AdEnrollSchedID, AdEnrollID, Date, StartTime, Attend, Absent, unitType, Status, Comment, Excused, ModFlag, UserID, DateAdded, DateLstMod, AdClassAttendID, Type)
        VALUES ('.$AdEnrollSchedID.','.$AdEnrollID.',\''.$date.'\',\'1899-12-30 07:00:00.000\','.$present.','.$absent.',\'M\',\'A\',\''.$comment.'\',0,\'A\','.$instructorID.
        ','.$date.','.$date.','.$AdClassAttendID.',\'A\')';
```

OR

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO AdAttend (AdEnrollSchedID, AdEnrollID, Date, StartTime, Attend, Absent, unitType, Status, Comment, Excused, ModFlag, UserID, DateAdded, DateLstMod, AdClassAttendID, Type)
        VALUES ('.$AdEnrollSchedID.','.$AdEnrollID.',"'.$date.'",\'1899-12-30 07:00:00.000\','.$present.','.$absent.',\'M\',\'A\',\''.$comment.'\',0,\'A\','.$instructorID.
        ','.$date.','.$date.','.$AdClassAttendID.',\'A\')';
```

Comment: your first example is missing the unescaped quotes needed for concatenation. - `\''.$date.'\'`

Comment: Option 2, with the double quotes doesn't seem to work.. Option 1 does, but I gotta give credit to Sean as he got it first.